# Logical Implications Quiz Help

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

These are fill in the blank questions.  I scored an 18 out of 25, but I don't see where I am making mistakes.  Please help me understand these conditional logic statements!

The answer options are:

1. IMPLIES (-->)
2. IS IMPLIED BY (<--)
3. IFF (<-->, both "IMPLIES" and "IS IMPLIED BY")
4. NONE OF THE ABOVE

I'm viewing these problems by saying "if P, then Q" in my head.  If that statement is true, then I mark IMPLIES.  I also check the converse: "if Q, then P."  If the converse is true, then I also mark IS IMPLIED BY.  Marking both is equivalent to IFF.  If neither "if P, then Q" or its converse are true, I mark NONE OF THE ABOVE.

1. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** x $\ge$ 1 Answer: NONE
2. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** x > 0 Answer: IMPLIES
3. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** x + 1 > 0 Answer: IMPLIES
4. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** x - 1 > 0 Answer: IFF
5. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** x$^2$ > 1 Answer: IMPLIES
6. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** x + y > y Answer: IMPLIES
7. x > 1 ***_*__*_*____** xy>y Answer: IFF
8. x>1 ***_*__*_*____** x>-x Answer: IMPLIES
9. x>1 ***_*__*_*____** x>y AND y>1 Answer: IMPLIED BY
10. x >1 ***_*__*_*____** x>y OR y>1 Answer: NONE
11. x>1 ***_*__*_*____** xy>y AND y>0 Answer: IMPLIED BY
12. x>1 ***_*__*_*____** xy>y OR y>0 Answer: NONE
13. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x$\le$1 Answer: NONE
14. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x<0 Answer: IMPLIED BY
15. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x+1 < 0 Answer: IMPLIED BY
16. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x-1 < 0 Answer: IFF
17. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x$^2$ < 1 Answer: NONE
18. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x+y $\le$ y Answer: IMPLIED BY
19. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** xy < y Answer: NONE
20. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x < z-x Answer: IFF
21. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x < y OR y < 1 Answer: NONE
22. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x < y AND y < 1 Answer: IMPLIED BY
23. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** xy < y OR y > 0 Answer: NONE
24. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** xy < y AND y > 0 Answer: IMPLIED BY
25. x<1 ***_*__*_*____** x < 0 OR x$^2$ < 1 Answer: IMPLIED BY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: If $x>1$, then it is certainly true that $x\geq 1$. The converse is false ($1\geq1$, but it is not the case that $1>1$). So, the answer should be "IMPLIES".

7: You have ignored the possibility that $y$ is negative. Take $x=2$ and $y=-1$. Then $x>1$, but $xy=-2<-1$. So, the forward implication is false.  The backward implication is false as well: take $x=-1$ and $y=-2$. Then $xy=2>-2$, but $x\leq 1$. So, the answer should be "NONE".

13: If $x< 1$, then certainly $x\leq1$; the converse doesn't need to hold. So the answer should be "IMPLIES".

17: It is true that $x<1$ does not imply $x^2<1$; take $x=-2$, for instance.  However, the converse holds: $x^2<1$ is equivalent to $-1<x<1$, which implies $x<1$. So, this should be "IMPLIED BY".

20: If $x=0$ and $z=-2$, then $x<1$ but $0=x>-2=z-x$; so, the forward implication doesn't hold.  On the other hand, if $x=2$ and $z=5$, then $x<z-x$ but it is not true that $x<1$. So, this should be "NONE".

21: The forward implication is true: if $x<1$, there are two cases: either $y<1$ or $y\geq 1$. If $y<1$, then the RHS is true; if $y\geq 1$ and $x<1$, then certainly $x<y$, making the RHS true. The backward implication is false: if $y=3$ and $x=2$, then RHS is satisfied, but it is not true that $x<1$. So, this should be "IMPLIES".

25: If $x<1$, there are two cases: $x<0$ or $0\leq x<1$. In the first case, RHS is satisfied; in the second, $0\leq x^2<1$, and so RHS is still satisfied. So, the forward implication is true. For the backward: if $x<0$, then $x<1$; if $x^2<1$, then $-1<x<1$, and so $x<1$. So, 25 should be "IFF".

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations!  Some of them seem obvious to me now.  However, I still don't understand the reasoning for number 17.  How does x^2 < 1 == -1 < x < 1?

Comment: Which part?  I'd be happy to try to explain further, if I know where you're getting lost.

Comment: OH, I see.  If x < -1, its square would be greater than 1.  So it must be a fractional value between -1 and 1!

Comment: Fractional is a dirty word, in this case - it makes it sound like you mean it must be rational, when it could of course be something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. But you are right in saying that it must be between -1 and 1.  This is equivalent to remembering that $x^2<a$ (where $a>0$) is equivalent to $\lvert x\rvert<\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand 21 as well.  I think I'm viewing these problems wrong.  The way I interpret the problem is: "If x < 1, then x < y or y < 1."  But, I selected "NONE" because there is no mention of the y variable on the LHS, I don't see how one could determine x's relationship to y at all.  Viewing it conversely, "If x < y OR y < 1, then x < 1" doesn't make sense to me either, again because there isn't a y variable on the LHS.  I know I must be viewing the problem incorrectly.

Comment: You need to think of "$x<y$ or $y<1$" as a single unit.  One way that's sometimes helpful: think of these sorts of statements as functions; they return True or False, depending on the statement.  In this thought process, you can think of "OR" statements _basically_ like piecewise functions: if $y<1$, then it returns True no matter what; if $y\geq 1$, then it evaluates the other condition.

Comment: After re-reading your explanation, it seems that the implication as a whole is TRUE whether or not the LHS is TRUE or FALSE, as long as the RHS is TRUE.  Is this is related to the truth table for P --> Q?

Comment: The fact that $y$ is only mentioned on one side is confusing at first, but doesn't really matter.  For instance: "$x<1$" certainly implies "$y>0$ or $y<=0$".  Why?  Because the latter statement (the "or" condition) is always satisfied, regardless of $x$.

Comment: Exactly right!  All that you care about is the truth value: if you ASSUME that LHS is true, does that necessarily imply that RHS is true?  If you ASSUME that RHS is true, does that necessarily imply that LHS is true?

Comment: Thank you!!  And were your last questions rhetorical?  I think that if I assume either side is true, it does not necessarily imply that the opposite side is true.

Comment: They weren't rhetorical - those questions are the entire point.  The statement "P implies Q" means, exactly, 'If P is true, must it be the case that Q is true?'  So, you _assume_ LHS is true, and see if you can either prove RHS or come up with a counterexample. Then, you do the reverse.

Comment: I believe I'm getting it!  I'll practice more.  Again, thank you very much for your help!